# ESP32 compiler giving "multiple definition of" errors

Tags: gcc, esp32

Got a new issue I've not come across before that's appeared when using the Espressif ESP32 ESP-IDF standard setup under VSCode. It uses the GNU compiler.

I'm getting "multiple definition of" errors on variables that share the same name, but which should be local.

So I use a .c and .h pair of files approach.

In my .c files I do this at the top

```
#define IO_EXPANDER_C       //<<<This is a unique define for this file pair
#include "io-pca9539.h"
```

In my .h files I do this:

```
#ifdef IO_EXPANDER_C
//----- INTERNAL ONLY MEMORY DEFINITIONS -----
uint8_t *NextReadDataPointer;


//----- INTERNAL & EXTERNAL MEMORY DEFINITIONS -----
//(Also defined below as extern)
int SomeVariableIWantAvailableGlobally;


#else
//----- EXTERNAL MEMORY DEFINITIONS -----
extern int SomeVariableIWantAvailableGlobally;


#endif
```

It's a great simple system, any other .c file that includes the .h file (without the #define above its include statemnt), gets all of its extern variables, none of its local variables.
But, compiling in VSCode with my ESP-IDF based project, I'm getting "multiple definition of" errors relating to "NextReadDataPointer"

I use the same variable name NextReadDataPointer in another file pair in just the same way, but it's never declared anywhere as extern and each file pair uses a separate #define (IO_EXPANDER_C and LED_C). I do this all the time normally and I can't see any obvious mistakes.

I've never seen a C compiler do this before, it's as if it's mixing up the local definitions somehow. A #define should only have scope in the file it is declared in and in any includes within that file.

Even odder, the error is not generated if the project is built but a function is called from just one of the file pairs that share the same local variable name. It's only generated when functions are called from both file pairs from my main application.

Can anyone shed light on whether the GNU C compiler does something funky for a standard ESP-IDF project as it's got me baffled?

Comment: Don't do it this way, it's confusing and error-prone. Never put variable definitions in `.h` files. All file-local variables should be declared `static` inside their respective `.c` files. All global variables should be *declared* `extern` (not defined, i.e. without an initialiser) in `.h` files and `defined` (without `extern` and/or with an initialiser) in exactly one `.c` file. This eliminates the need for anything like `#ifdef IO_EXPANDER_C` etc. These macros are too too easy to misuse.

Comment: Sorry I disagree, its a great way of writing drivers that's proved itself a good and solid KISS approach over many years for us.  Not a problem that it isn't for you, but my question is specifically about why this error is being generated, each to their own on programming styles :-)

Comment: I have never seen anything this convoluted and unnecessary being described as "KISS", but you do you.

Comment: KISS as in it keeps everything in one place. When we declare any variable outside of a function (so global) we always do it in the same place in the header file.  Far simpler (in my opinion) than .c files with global scope variable definitions all over the place, makes it really easy to debug and understand whats been used and whats local scope to the files and whats intended to be global to the whole project. Same with functions too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`uint8_t *NextReadDataPointer;` creates a variable which is visible across all translation units, i.e. it's the opposite of "private". If you include this header in multiple c files and the linker tries to link those together; it'll see a conflict. The keyword you're looking for is `static`, for example `static uint8_t *NextReadDataPointer;` creates a variable that is not visible across translation units. The reason you don't see the problem if calling a function from only one of those two files is because in this case the linker doesn't bother looking into the other one.

Personally I'd avoid such clever preprocessor hacks because it's quite difficult to see how files include one another and debug the resulting problems. I'd suggest sticking to the standard way of declaring shared things in header files and keeping the private stuff inside the c file (prepended by `static`).

Comment: Thank you, I'm confused though in that I've never had to use static before.  I'd like to understand why its appeared as an issue now. The approach in my question has worked fine across all sorts of embedded c projects in the past and with GCC in the past on other platforms (e.g. under Linux for the Raspberry Pi). We use it for functions and variables and I never normally use static. Is it possible there is some GCC config option that's causing this that I've not encountered before, or could it be related to this project being set up as C++ somewhere over standard C I wonder?

Comment: Your approach works fine by accident. GCC only does what you've instructed it to do :)

Comment: Well you're quite right of course and thank you for your answer. If I leave everything as is and just add static in front of both the local NextReadDataPointer variable definitions the error vanishes.  I'm amazed I've gone so long and through so many other compilers too with it just working!  Looks like I need to refresh my knowledge of GCC static...

Comment: Thinking about it, of course it requires a name collision for the error to appear. It's possible I just got lucky on past GCC based projects and didn't happen to share the same name globally (I'm a bit of stickler for longer explanatory names so that could make sense)